# ptrace(), how can i stop getting traced in child process?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ptrace

I want to trace only a part of C program for system calls. I am using ptrace() with PTRACE_TRACEME option to start getting traced. How to stop this process from getting traced after few lines of code. I am trying to use PTRACE_DETACH but it does not work?

The main .C file is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/ptrace.h>
#include<signal.h>

int display(char *p);
int main()
{
    puts("Before Display\n");   
    display("hello");
    puts("After Display\n");
    return 0;
}

int display(char *p)
{
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
    raise(SIGCONT);
    puts("interception");
    ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, 0, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The code of parent process is:

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>   /* For constants ORIG_EAX etc */
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   pid_t child;
    int status;
    long orig_eax;
    child = fork();
    if(child == 0) 
    {
        execl("/home/kashi/Documents/write", "write", NULL);
    }
    else {
      while(1)
      {
        wait(&status);
          if(WIFEXITED(status))
              break;
        orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                          child, 4 * ORIG_EAX,
                          NULL);
        printf("The child made a "
               "system call %ld\n", orig_eax);
       ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, child, NULL, NULL);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it from the traced process.

`PTRACE_TRACEME` is the **only** request that makes sense in the traced process. `PTRACE_DETACH` and all the others must be used in the tracing process.

The tracee can communicate with the tracer and ask it politely to detach. There's no `ptrace` request specifically for that. The tracee can e.g. `raise(SIGCONT)`, the tracer will observe it and issue `PTRACE_DETACH`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the doubt. Could you please suggest some good reference for ptrace() and its use.